# Drupal: How do I have a module enabled for one theme, but not another?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-themes

I have installed the LogoTool module, but I only want it enabled in the custom theme used for the front end site, not for the Garland theme used in the administrative back end. How do I do that?

Best regards, Egil.

Answer (score 1):

Does this module provide block? If yes, you can control block visibility here admin/build/block/list (see secondary tabs below title) or click on configure besides block and change visibility settings.

or do it dirty way... display:none; in css file for logo div inside body class "section-admin"

Comment: So, more generally, there is no way to disable any module (with or without a block) on a per theme basis?

Comment: you are doing it wrong in general. you don't want to turn module on and off, you want it's content to not show up in particular theme or part of web site.

Comment: Exactly. The theme modifies the module output, not the other way around. It is possible to use theming or a very simple site customization module to change module behavior/output. Which module is it?

Comment: Egil Hansen says LogoTool module